# Can't send error params to error middleware on an async way in Express

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, error-handling

Currently I have a middleware using Express but I can't launch an error with the same format Express uses because it's a sync function so things like `next(err)` simply doesn't work.

I could send an error with `throw` and the application does not crash so it's fine, but I cant set some params such as `err.message` or `err.statusCode`. This is the code working:

```
function getScope(req, res, next){
    //req.scopesArray is an array of arrays: [ ['RESOURCE','.ACTION'] , ['patient','.create'] ]
    req.scopesArray.forEach(function(current,index,array){
        switch(req.scopesArray){
            case 'user': var hasPermissions = checkUserPermissions(permissionId,action); break;
        }                    
        if(!hasPermissions) throw new Error('Error with permissions');
    });
    next();
}
```

I've realized that, event not calling `next(err)`, the error middleware does execute.

I've tried thinks like:

```
var err = {}; err.message = 'test'; err.statusCode=404;
throw new Error(err);
```

But has not worked.

How could I send an async error to the error middleware but being able to set err values? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not just return response with your message and status code from the middleware ?

Comment: ^^this, why not just return `if(!hasPermissions)  res.render('error', { message: 'Error with permission, status: 500 });`